# Are the limits for Google Cloud's Always Free on a per-project or per-account basis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently, Google Cloud Platform offers "1 non-preemptible f1-micro VM instance per month" amongst other things, for free, as part of its [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) tier.

However, I can't determine if the limits assigned to the free tier, like the single f1-micro instance, are per-account (ie, for a single Google email address), or per-project.

Basically: if I make another GCP project under the same account, can I run another f1-micro for free, or will the second one cost me?

Comment: Free Tier / Always Free is per account

Comment: Asking about contract terms is barely [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @JohnHanley do you have a source for that assertion? If so I'm happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: To quote Google, "Always Free isn't a special program. It's a regular part of your Google Cloud account." [end quote] This offering requires a billing account and is not based upon a project. https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=vi#always-free

Comment: Okay that quote is the closest thing to a definitive statement that I can find. Again, happy to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The always free tier depends on the [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=vi#always-free)

This means that this limits are shared by the different projects you have under the same billing account.

So what you were asking of having an additional VM on another project will not be free, however you can create another account and have this additional VM on this account and that one will be free.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? Happy to accept it if true

Comment: I added the documentation on the answer, and I tested with one of my projects

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation available at [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits) ,

> Your Always Free f1-micro instance limit is by time, not by instance.
>   Each month, eligible use of all of your f1-micro instances is free
>   until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the
>   current month. Usage calculations are combined across the supported
>   regions.

So to answer your question, you will get charged based on the amount of time you use the instance(s)

Comment: Always **free** won't be charged at all, so how this answer the question?

Comment: I read that section, but to me it doesn't answer the question. So yes there's a time-based limit, but is that limit one month per account, or per project?

Comment: Total number of instance hours used on your account (irrespective of the number of projects).  e.g. For a month having 30 days X 24 Hours a day = 720 instance hours of the f1-micro instance would be free. You can divide that across 1, 2, 10 instance and stay within total 720. Beyond that charges start incurring

Comment: @Martin Zeitler I have 3 google accounts. a, b, c . Do you mean that if I want to create a free free tier in c, Should I have to delete all payment methods in a and b? a and b are not in use now.

Answer (score 1):

[Always Free resources are calculated per billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free). (not the email itself).

So you don't have to create a new email to have an additional VM, just add a new billing account and link it to a different project, then you can have another free  VM on that project.

I will try it this month, i am setting up two VM in two different projects linked to two different billing accounts all under single email, i will let you know if it worked.

Comment: When I create a new billing account, under the same Google email account, do I add the same credit card or do I have to add a different credit card for each billing account?